# Grouping array element in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Direct to Exhibitors 
        [1] =>  IMTEX Website
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Direct to Exhibitors 
        [1] =>  EDM
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Visitors Promotion in General
        [1] => Digital
        [2] => Mobile Apps
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Visitor Promotion in General
        [1] => Digital
        [2] => IMTEX Website
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Visitor Promotion in Genral
        [1] => Mass Media
        [2] => Print Media
    )

)
```

And I want the output in this format

```
Array 
(
[Direct to Exhibitors] => Array
    (
        [0] => IMTEX Website
        [1] => EDM
    )

[Visitors Promotion in General] => Array
    (
        [Digital] => Array
            (
                [0] => Mobile Apps
                [1] => IMTEX Website
            )

        [Mass Media] => Array
            (
                [0] => Print Media
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple foreach will do:

```
<?php

$arr = [
['Visitors Promotion in General','Digital','Mobile Apps'],
['Visitors Promotion in General','Digital','IMTEX Website'],
['Visitors Promotion in General','Mass Media','Print Media']
];

$finalArr = [];

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $finalArr[$value[0]][$value[1]][] = $value[2];
}

print_r($finalArr);
```

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [Visitors Promotion in General] => Array
        (
            [Digital] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mobile Apps
                    [1] => IMTEX Website
                )

            [Mass Media] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Print Media
                )

        )

)
```

**Update 1,2:**  Dynamic size 2/3 elements

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if(isset($value[2]))
        $finalArr[$value[0]][$value[1]][] = $value[2];
    else
        $finalArr[$value[0]][] = $value[1];
}
```

**Update 3:** Dynamic size n elements

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $tempArr = [];
    foreach (array_reverse($value) as $arr) {
        $tempArr = [$arr => $tempArr];
    }
    $finalArr = array_replace_recursive($finalArr,$tempArr);
}
```

[But now final array also an array, finding a way to convert it into elements]

For this input:

```
$arr = [
['Visitors Promotion in General','Digital','Mobile Apps'],
['Visitors Promotion in General','Digital','Web Apps'],
['Direct to Exhibitors','EDM'],
['Visitors Promotion in General','Digital'],
['Visitors Promotion in General','Mass Media','Print Media'],
['Visitors Promotion in General','Mass Media','Print Media','Mass'],
['Direct to Exhibitors','IMTEX Website']
];
```

is the output:

```
Array
(
    [Visitors Promotion in General] => Array
        (
            [Digital] => Array
                (
                    [Mobile Apps] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [Web Apps] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [Mass Media] => Array
                (
                    [Print Media] => Array
                        (
                            [Mass] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [Direct to Exhibitors] => Array
        (
            [EDM] => Array
                (
                )

            [IMTEX Website] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Trying with this workaround:

```
function findEmpty($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value) && !empty($value)){
            $arr[$key] = findEmpty($value);
        } else {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

print_r(findEmpty($finalArr));
```

Comment: what will happen if the array length is not fixed; means if the one array has only two elements and other has three elements(size is not fixed)

Comment: We may need to handle that too.. So will it atleast has 2? See the updated one

Comment: Can you see my question again, it has array with size 2, 3, the size can be 4 or it can be 5... also. I have to group based on that

Comment: What about size 4,5,6 ...... , if array size is dynamic. Will I have to add if else based on the size of the array. Is there not any generic solution which is applicable for all size of array

Comment: @ankit Updated. Still a final step missing